# How Can I Get a Private Feed from Instagram?

Tags: javascript, instagram

I want to display a private feed, embedded in a website. Hopefully solely using JavaScript. Bonus points for React, though I'll manage without. Instagram's API seems to solely reference displaying individual posts. Third party tools all seem to either already not work or indicate they won't work on March 2nd, when Instagram changes their API. Since it's private, is there an embed code I can use that would do the logging in for me?

What's the best way - if possible - to display a private feed? Especially if it works after the API switch.

I've never even used Instagram, so I don't know where to begin. I might not even be using proper terminology. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a private group feed?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my question. There's no special "group" delineation. It's an account for a business that is private. They talk about it like a group. I'll remove that. It's just a private account.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use https://fetchrss.com/ it is free for a few feeds. I am concerned about the API change, hope this service is not affected. It generates an RSS feed (obviously) which you will have to parse but it is stupid easy to create the feed.

Comment: Trying this morning, it isn't working, even for public feeds :(